# On form.submit method add header issue

Tags: javascript, extjs, http-headers, token, form-submit

Submit method in my form to upload image and text fields

Here is my code:

```
var form = Ext.getCmp('form');
form.submit({
    url: webAPI+'setting/updateCityInformation',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        token: getCookie("requestToken")
    },
    success: function(form, action) {
        console.log('success');
    },
    failure: function(form, action) {
    }
});
```

The token is not adding in this method please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a common function for all form submit methods:

```
Ext.Ajax.on("beforerequest", function(event, request) {
       if(request.headers && request.headers.token) {
            request.headers.token = getCookie("requestToken");
       }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use useDefaultXhrHeader:false

```
useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
headers: {
  'token': getCookie("requestToken"),
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
}
```

Comment: He want to upload data, the content-type has to be set as `multipart/form-data`

Comment: HI @AjayThakur still same issue

Comment: @RaviPatidar can you post all header here which are passed in a url?

Comment: HI @AjayThakur

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:49302
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarypnleLkFE46xU2b50
Cookie:PHPSESSID=
Host:avunea.svn
Origin:http://test.svn
Referer:http://test.svn/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36

Comment: @RaviPatidar form.submit function doesn't support setting headers.
you can refer this link: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?121750-How-can-I-add-headers-to-getForm-Submit()-calls